# Why is an inline static variable of a template class not initialized?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, inline

### Minimal example and question

In this example, an inline static member variable `c2` of a nontemplate class is initialized when the class member is instantiated, and member variable `c1` of a template class is not. What is the difference? Why is `c1` not being initialized unless I force it to be by taking its address, and `c2` is initialized unconditionally?

```
struct C1 {                        
    C1() { std::cerr << "C1()\n"; }
};                                 


struct C2 {                        
    C2() { std::cerr << "C2()\n"; }
};                                 

template<typename T>               
struct Template {                  
    inline static C1 c1;           
};                                 

struct Nontemplate {                
    inline static C2 c2;           
};                                 

int main() {                       
    Template<int> a;               
    Nontemplate b;                  
    (void)a;                       
    (void)b;                       
}
// Output:
C2()
```

### Context and reasoning

Here's a bit of context to the minimal example. I have the `Nontemplate` class inherited from `Template<something>`, and the constructor of `c2` depends on `c1`. I expect `c1` to be created before `c2`; however, that is not the case.

```
template<typename T>                                                     
struct Template {                                                        
    inline static C1 c1;                                                 
};                                                                       

struct Nontemplate : public Template<int> {                               
    struct C2 {                                                          
        C2() {                                                           
            std::cerr << "Do something with Nontemplate::C1\n";          
            std::cerr << "&Nontemplate::c1 = " << &Nontemplate::c1 << "\n";
        }                                                                
    };                                                                   
    inline static C2 c2;                                                 
};                                                                       

int main() {                                                             
    Nontemplate b;                                                        
    (void)b;                                                             
}                                                                        
// Output:
Do something with Nontemplate::C1
&Nontemplate::c1 = 0x600ea8       
C1()
```

The code was compiled with g++ 7.2 with `-std=c++17` flags. Both `-O0` and `-O2` give the same result.

Comment: What compiler(s)? Is it consistent between implementations? (Various static initialization is “quirky” between several Clang / GCC / ICC versions, regardless of what standards reading might indicate..)

Comment: @user2864740 g++ 7.2. I updated the question.

Comment: In the first example, `c1` is not created because you don't use it anywhere. (The same applies to member functions of template classes.) There are [ways](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jaVAPL) to trick the compiler into creating `c1`, but as you noticed, even if `c1` is constructed, it may or may not be constructed before `c2`, see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Dynamic_initialization) for details. To enforce specific construction order, move `c1` to some function (and keep it static, then it'll be constructed when the declaration is reached for the first time).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So, static variables of template classes belong to dynamic initialization, and static variables of nontemplate classes to static initialization? That explains everything. Seems that I shouldn't solve the problem this way. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat >"because you don't use it anywhere" Just a remark - I noted this in the post ("unless I force it to do so taking its address"), the main question was in the difference between template and non-template.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Nah, static initialization is essentially for variables with `constexpr` constructors/initializers. Otherwise static variables of non-template classes are initialized as a part of dynamic init ("ordered dynamic initialization"). *"Just a remark - I noted this in the post"* Yes, sorry, my comment was a bit rushed. *"Could you please post it as an answer"* I don't really have time to write a full-blown answer right now. :/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed, I missed it at a first glance. Though it still hardly can be abused. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implicit instantiation of a class template only causes instantiation of the declarations it contains. Definitions are generally only instantiated when they are used in a context that requires the definition to exist.

So as long as you don't use `Template<int>::c1` in a way that would require its definition to exist (i.e. by odr-using it), then it will not be defined at all.

One way of odr-using the variable is to take its address, as you mentioned.

Even if you force the instantiation of the variable, there is no guarantee when exactly it will be initialized.

`C1`'s constructor is not `constexpr` and so the initialization of `Nontemlate::c1` cannot be a constant expression. This means that you are going to get dynamic initialization of `Template<int>::c1`. Dynamic initialization of global static variables which are part of a template specialization are *unordered*, meaning that there is no guarantee in what order they will happen relative to any other dynamic initialization of global static variables.

Similarly `Nontemlate::c2` is not initialized by a constant expression and so is also dynamically initialized. Although `Nontemlate::c2` has *partially ordered dynamic initialization* (being an `inline` variable not part of a template specialization), it is still indeterminately sequenced relative to `Template<int>::c1` as explained above.

It is also not strictly required that `Template<int>::c1` and `Nontemlate::c2` are initialized before `main` is entered. It is implementation-defined whether initialization is deferred until later, but before the first odr-use of the respective variable. I think this deferral is used mainly for runtime dynamic library loading, though.

A common method to avoid ordering issues of global static storage duration variables is to use a function returning a reference to a local static variable instead, i.e.:

```
template<typename T>               
struct Template {                  
    static auto& c1() {
        static C1 instance; 
        return instance;
    }          
};
```

although this may have a performance impact when called often, because the construction of the local static must be checked each time.

Alternative, if the initializer can be made a constant expression, making the variable `constexpr` should guarantee *constant initialization*, meaning that no dynamic initialization will happen at all and no ordering issues will be present.